# Moonbeam Parachain staking

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain, parachain-collator, moonbeam

I have added parachain staking and moonbeam-orbiters of moonbeam in our project. When I test it, all the extrinsics are performing well except the staking part. I have gone through this https://docs.moonbeam.network/tokens/staking/stake/#staking-your-tokens
Here, it is mentioned that "**To access staking features, you need to import/create an Ethereum-style account first (H160 address),**"
Can we access staking features with a normal account? Like If I perform delegate extrinsics with a normal account, staking tokens reflected in the reserve amount of the delegator account(**EVE**)(As mentioned in above tutorial). But in my case the Eve account is not getting any reward.
[image]

### Some Setup details: 1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]

What should I do to get reward ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also transfer some money from one account to another for getting some fees which can be our reward.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about the setup, this is how Delegator **Eve** ends up getting a reward, when a candidate **Alice** creates a block:

To receive a reward, the following parameters are important:
`defaultBlocksPerRound` (default 600) and `rewardPaymentDelay` (default 2).

Using the above values, a single round goes on for `600` blocks, where **Alice** may create N (of total) number of blocks and gets points awarded for it accordingly. The storage items `round` and `points` can be used to observe the current round, and the total points that are rewarded currently to all candidates.

Once a round is complete, `rewardPaymentDelay` comes into play, so **Eve** will be awarded after `2` rounds, i.e. after `1200` (2 * 600) blocks once the current round has ended. The reward will only be awarded to the candidate and their delegators that are present in the `topDelegations` storage item.

**EDIT:**

EventHandler implementation for staking pallet:

```
impl pallet_author_inherent::Config for Runtime {
    type SlotBeacon = RelaychainBlockNumberProvider<Self>;
    type AccountLookup = MoonbeamOrbiters;

    type EventHandler = ParachainStaking; // This calls the staking pallet
                                          // when a block is produced
    type CanAuthor = AuthorFilter;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_author_inherent::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}
```

Comment: I have set defaultBlocksPerRound : 16, rewardPaymentDelay : 2. For topDelegations I have attached the image in question. But I don't get any reward after 2 round

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. In one of the images, I see that the `points` value is actually 0. Could you check that for the previous round? You can also check if `awardedPts` for the previous round and collator are actually non-zero. It might just be that the collator never produced a block.

Comment: I have checked **points** and **awardedPts** for previous round as well but it shows 0. How I can check that collator is produced block or not ?

Comment: The only way to check that would be to see the authors of previous blocks. The information is also visible on polkadotjs Explorer home page, where recent blocks are listed. On their right is the collator that produced the block. If the collator is listed but the points for them for the current round is 0, then something is indeed wrong.

Comment: Additionally, the `note_author` handler must be invoked from the consensus (we use [nimbus](https://github.com/PureStake/nimbus/blob/main/pallets/author-inherent/src/lib.rs#L115)), that informs the staking pallet of the authorship and allows it to assign points to the author.

Comment: Now I joined charlie as a collator but Blocks are still produced by alice(added photo above).  for note_author, I import the whole parachain-staking and moonbeam-orbiter in our project. I have also added some more photos of code above please take a look.

Comment: If this is in `--dev` mode then only **Alice** is supported as the block author.

Comment: using these commands ./target/release/polkadot \                                                     
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain rococo-raw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944                                                                                                               **2.  ./target/release/polkadot \                                                     
--bob \  
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay-bob \  
--chain rococo-raw.json \
--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/ALICE KEY \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9945**

Comment: Using this command to start parachain: ./target/release/hero --alice \                                                 
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
--rpc-port 6969 \
--rpc-cors all \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977

Comment: I added an edit to the answer on how the staking pallet is informed of block authorship via  pallet_author_inherent from nimbus.

Comment: Do I need to delete the inbuilt authorship after adding pallet_author_inherent ? Because If I didn't delete this error is shown: **Block import error: State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted**

Comment: Yeah at a given time only a single authorship pallet must be enabled and it should be able to callback Staking for rewards to be distributed

Comment: do we have any sample in which anyone have added the parachain-staking in the cumulus-node-template?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such example that might exist.

Comment: How to integrate nimbus in our node(service.rs, chain_spec, rpc.rs) on version v0.9.24 ?

Comment: The template here https://github.com/PureStake/nimbus/tree/main/parachain-template and the README file should describe the requisities.